# How to write the adapter class for the following recycler view?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a Todo app and I have done the Room part and able to store data now I want to display the data in the form of Recycler View but I am not getting how to write the adapter class corresponding to it. I looked for it in different sites I never got any satisfying answer.

**TodoFragViewModel.kt""

```
class TodofragViewModel(
    val database: TodoDao, applicaltion: Application
): AndroidViewModel(applicaltion) {
    // TODO: Implement the ViewModel
    /**
     * viewModelJob allows us to cancel all coroutines started by this ViewModel.
     */
    private var viewModelJob = Job()

    /**All coroutines can be cancelled by viewmodelJob.cancel() and Dispatcher.main is byDefault choice
     */
    private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

    private val currenctTodo = MutableLiveData<Todo?>()

    private val allTodo = database.getAllTodo()


    init{
        intializeThisTodo()
    }

    private fun intializeThisTodo(){
        uiScope.launch {
            currenctTodo.value=getFromDatabase()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getFromDatabase(): Todo? {
        return  withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
            val info =database.getCurrentTodo()
            info

        }
    }



    private suspend fun insert(thisTodo: Todo) {

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            database.insert(thisTodo)
            Log.i("Database","${database.getCurrentTodo()?.description} and ${database.getCurrentTodo()?.time}")
        }


    }


    fun onAdded(time:String,description:String) {

        uiScope.launch {

            val thisTodo = Todo(time,description)

            insert(thisTodo)

            currenctTodo.value=getFromDatabase()


        }

    }


    /**
     * Called when the ViewModel is dismantled.
     * At this point, we want to cancel all coroutines;
     * otherwise we end up with processes that have nowhere to return to
     * using memory and resources.
     */
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        viewModelJob.cancel()
    }

}
```

**todo_recycler_view**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todo_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/date_text" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**TodoFrag.kt**

```
class todofrag : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = todofrag()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: TodofragViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.todofrag_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dataSource= TodoDatabase.getInstance(application)?.InformationDatabaseDao

        val viewModelFactory = dataSource?.let { TodoViewModelFactory(it, application) }
        val viewModel=ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(TodofragViewModel::class.java)


        add_button.setOnClickListener{
            val currentDate: String = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            val currentTime: String = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())

            val time:String="${currentDate} \n ${currentTime}"

            viewModel.onAdded(time,todo_text.text.toString())

        }

    }

}
```

Please let me know if any other files are added. By the way, I tried to use card view so that it looked good.

Answer (score 0):

The [developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter) explains it pretty well.

This might not be perfectly suited for what you need, but it should be a good start. Specifically, I don't know all the fields for your Todo class, so make sure you account for those in this code.

Basically, you'll want to have a `ViewHolder` that represents your `CardView`

```
class TodoViewHolder(convertView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(convertView) {
  val dateText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_text)
  val description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.todo_description)
  // whatever else you need access to
}
```

And you'll want to use `DiffUtil` for a better user experience. This allows for some animations when things in the list change, such as removing an item, editing an item, or adding an item.

```
private class TodoDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Todo>() {
  override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Todo, newItem: Todo) =
    oldItem.id == newItem.id

  override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Todo, newItem: Todo) =
    oldItem.dateText == newItem.dateText && oldItem.description == newItem.description

}
```

You'll want to extend `ListAdapter` and override its methods. `onCreateViewHolder` creates an instance of your `TodoViewHolder` for each view that is seen and `onBindViewHolder` allows you to add behavior to each item in the list. It is worth noting that you can pass parameter into the adapter in case you need to.

```
class MyListAdapter : ListAdapter<Todo, TodoViewHolder>(TodoDiffCallback()) {
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = TodoViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.todo_recycler_view, parent, false))

  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val todo = getItem(position)
    holder.dateText = todo.dateText
    holder.description = todo.description
    // add whatever click listener and other stuff you need
  }
}
```

In your fragment, when you access your `RecyclerView`, just add an instance of the adapter if it's null.

```
if (recyclerView.adapter == null) {
  recyclerView.adapter = TotoListAdapter()
}
```

And when you want to add data (that you have retrieved from Room or your API) to the adapter (in the fragment/activity), just do the following:

```
(recyclerView.adapter as? TodoListAdapter)?.submitList(data)
```

On a side note, make sure to clean up your style (you can use the `Reformat Code` command in the `Code` menu), and you would want to rename the `todo_recycler_view` to something like `todo_view`. You'll want to have a `RecyclerView` layout in your fragment layout.

Comment: I have doubt, here ```(recyclerView.adapter as? TodoListAdapter)?.submitList(data)``` where are receiving the data, means the above code is in the fragment file and but where are we accepting it in adapter file.

Comment: @AshutoshPanda I'm not entirely sure that I understand your comment. Yes, the call to `submitList` is in the fragment (like in the `observe` callback of a LiveData, which might get it from a repository, which might get it either from a server or Room or Sqlite). The adapter will take care of the rest, so you do not need to have additional code to receive the data in the adapter. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I mean where is the body of the function   ** submitList(data)  **?

Comment: That's a function of the adapter. You don't need to create it or override it. It will use the DiffUtil to see if anything in the list has changed and do the necessary updates to your views. See https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter for further information

Comment: If you want to explore the innards of functions and classes, right-click on the function, click Go To, and Declaration and Usages. That will bring you to the source code for it. If you are on a Mac, the shortcut is command-B. You'll have to look up the shortcut if you are on PC.